# How to AND predicates in the WHERE clause in a LINQ to RavenDB query

Tags: linq, ravendb

I have the following model:

```
public class Clip {
    public Guid ClipId { get; set; }
    public IList<StateChange> StateChanges { get; set; }
}

public class StateChange {
    public string OldState { get; set; }
    public string NewState { get; set; }
    public DateTime ChangedAt { get; set; }
}
```

And this is how a query raven:

```
var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
var since = now.AddSeconds(60);
string state = "some state of interest";
using (var session = docStore.OpenSession()) {
            RavenQueryStatistics stats;
            session.Query<Clip>()
                .Statistics(out stats)
                .Where(
                    p => p.StateChanges.Any(a => (since > a.ChangedAt && a.NewState == state))
                    && !p.StateChanges.Any(a => (a.OldState == state && now > a.ChangedAt)))
                .ToArray();
            return stats.TotalResults;
        }
```

I want to get the count for all `Clip` records that have a (`StateChange.CreatedAt` before `since` and `NewState` is `"some state of interest"`) AND NOT have a (`StateChange.CreatedAt` before `now` and `OldState` is `"some state of interest"`).

While the predicate used above works in linq to object, it doesn't seem to work in linq to raven (i.e. does not return the expected result). I suspect that this is because the expression `&& !.p.StateChanges.Any....` is never evaluated if the expression on the left-hand side evaluates to true. Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: What do you mean by "Doesn't work"? Is there an error?

Comment: No, it means that it does not return the expected results, i.e. ignores the right-hand side expression

Comment: How do you know it ignores it? If the first condition is true, it must evaluate the right condition to get the whole condition result.

Comment: @AmiramKorach yes, this is what it does when you work on a collection of objects. But it is not the case then the predicate is converted into a Lucene query string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not related to the evaluation of conditions. && works just fine.

The problem is that RavenDB doesn't properly handle queries that use .All(...) or !.Any(...).  This is due to the way raven's dynamic index engine evaluates your linq statement.  It wants to build a separate index entry for each of your StateChange entries, which won't work for operations that need to consider multiple related items, such as the different state changes.

There is an issue already logged for this [here](http://issues.hibernatingrhinos.com/issue/RavenDB-732).  It was closed in build 2151 to throw back a meaningful exception when you try to query in this way.  Maybe at some future date they can reassess if there's some way to actually evaluate these types of queries properly instead.

**Update**

I've been thinking about your challenge, and [another related one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13731255/634824), and was able to come up with a new technique that will allow you to do this.  It will require a static index and lucene query:

```
public class Clips_ByStateChange : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Clip>
{
  public Clips_ByStateChange()
  {
    Map = clips =>
          from clip in clips
          select new {
              OldState = clip.StateChanges
                  .Select(x => x.OldState + "|" + x.ChangedAt.ToString("o")),
              NewState = clip.StateChanges
                  .Select(x => x.NewState + "|" + x.ChangedAt.ToString("o"))
          };
  }
}

var results = session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<Clip, Clips_ByStateChange>()
    .Where(string.Format(
        "NewState: {{{0}|* TO {0}|{1}}} AND -OldState: {{{0}|* TO {0}|{2}}}",
        state, since.ToString("o"), now.ToString("o")));
```

Of course, you can still just take statistics on it if that's what you want.