# Find all items where child collection doesn't contain an item

Tags: linq, ravendb

Given:

```
public class Order
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<LineItem> LineItems {get; set;}
}

public class LineItem
{
   public string Product {get; set;}
   public int Quantity {get; set;}
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to construct a query that will return all the Orders that **don't** have a LineItem with a Product called "Apple"

Answer (score 4):

I've been thinking about this for awhile.  It's come up a few times.  The problem is that Raven doesn't currently handle !.Any() or .All() queries.

This particular example simplified the problem enough that it got me thinking down a different path.  I believe there is a solution.  It requires a lucene query against a static index:

```
public class Orders_ByProduct : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Order>
{
  public Orders_ByProduct()
  {
    Map = orders => from order in orders
                    select new
                    {
                        Product = order.LineItems.Select(x => x.Product)
                    };
  }
}

var ordersWithoutApple = session.Advanced
                                .LuceneQuery<Order, Orders_ByProduct>()
                                .Where("*:* AND -Product: Apple")
```

Comment: See also wizzardz's answer which uses the same index form, but he figured out how to express the query in simple linq.

Comment: This also works great when one would want to do a `.Except` between two collections, or a `.Any && !.Any`, e.g. I wanted to find all groups that a User was part of but not active in and the **Linq** I had was: `.Where(g => g.AllUserIdsInGroup.Any(id => userId == id) && !g.ActiveUserIdsInGroup.Any(id => userId == id))` which failed because of !.Any, but this **Lucene query** worked: `"AllUserIdsInGroup:234 AND -ActiveUserIdsInGroup:234"`

Answer (score 3):

We were able to work around RavenDB's lack of support for `!.Any` with an explicit comparison to `false`, like:

```
orders.Where(x => x.LineItems.Any(y => y.Product == "Apple") == false)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do that by creating an index for your query

```
public class GetOrdersByProductIndex: AbstractIndexCreationTask<Order,GetOrdersByProductIndex.Result>
{
  public class Result
  {
     public string Product {get; set;}
  }

  public GetOrdersByProductIndex()
  {
    Map = orders => from order in orders
                    select new
                    {
                        Product = order.LineItems.Select(x => x.Product)
                    };
  }
}
```

Now you can use this index to get your orders. Your query should look like this

```
 using(IDocumentSession session = docStore.OpenSession())
{
   var orders  = session.Query<GetOrdersByProductIndex.Result,GetOrdersByProductIndex>
                        .Where(x=>x.Product != "Apple")
                        .As<Order>()
                        .ToList()
}
```

Please note that by default it will return only 128 records(because of the limit set by ravendb) , if your query results have more than 128 records you should use `Take(recordsNeeded)` function for fetching the data.

Comment: Well I feel silly - that linq translates to "(-Product:Apple AND Product:*)" which is almost the same lucene that I wrote.  I couldn't for the life of me figure out how to represent the negation.  A simple != seems to work just fine. Thanks!